# apply a php function into Magento price

Tags: php, magento, numbers

i wanna change Magento price view to my language. i mean i want to change numbers.

i have this php function:

```
function fanum($englishnumbers)
{
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’0′ , ‘٠’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’1′ , ‘١’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’2′ , ‘٢’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’3′ , ‘٣’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’4′ , ‘۴’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’5′ , ‘۵’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’6′ , ‘۶’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’7′ , ‘٧’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’8′ , ‘٨’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’9′ , ‘٩’ , $englishnumbers);

return $englishnumbers;
}
```

and:

```
$echo fanum($en_number);
```

how to apply these in magento price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below snippet

```
public function convertNumber($num)
{


   list($num, $dec) = explode(".", $num);

   $output = "";

   if($num{0} == "-")
   {
      $output = "negative ";
      $num = ltrim($num, "-");
   }
   else if($num{0} == "+")
   {
      $output = "positive ";
      $num = ltrim($num, "+");
   }


   if($num{0} == "0")
   {
      $output .= "Zero";
   }
   else
   {
      $num = str_pad($num, 36, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      $group = rtrim(chunk_split($num, 3, " "), " ");
      $groups = explode(" ", $group);

      $groups2 = array();
      foreach($groups as $g) {
      $groups2[] = $this->convertThreeDigit($g{0}, $g{1}, $g{2});
      }

      for($z = 0; $z < count($groups2); $z++)
      {
         if($groups2[$z] != "")
         {
            $output .= $groups2[$z].$this->convertGroup(11 - $z).($z < 11 && !array_search('', array_slice($groups2, $z + 1, -1))
             && $groups2[11] != '' && $groups[11]{0} == '0' ? " and " : ", ");
         }
      }

      $output = rtrim($output, ", ");
   }

   if($dec > 0)
   {
      $output .= " point";
      for($i = 0; $i < strlen($dec); $i++) $output .= " ".$this->convertDigit($dec{$i});
   }

   return $output;
}

public function convertGroup($index)
{
   switch($index)
   {
      case 11: return " Decillion";
      case 10: return " Nonillion";
      case 9: return " Octillion";
      case 8: return " Septillion";
      case 7: return " Sextillion";
      case 6: return " Quintrillion";
      case 5: return " Quadrillion";
      case 4: return " Trillion";
      case 3: return " Billion";
      case 2: return " Million";
      case 1: return " Thousand";
      case 0: return "";
   }
}

public function convertThreeDigit($dig1, $dig2, $dig3)
{

   $output = "";

   if($dig1 == "0" && $dig2 == "0" && $dig3 == "0") return "";

   if($dig1 != "0")
   {
      $output .= $this->convertDigit($dig1)." Hundred";
      if($dig2 != "0" || $dig3 != "0") $output .= " and ";
   }

   if($dig2 != "0") $output .= $this->convertTwoDigit($dig2, $dig3);
   else if($dig3 != "0") $output .= $this->convertDigit($dig3);

   return $output;
}

public function convertTwoDigit($dig1, $dig2)
{
   if($dig2 == "0")
   {
      switch($dig1)
      {
         case "1": return "Ten";
         case "2": return "Twenty";
         case "3": return "Thirty";
         case "4": return "Forty";
         case "5": return "Fifty";
         case "6": return "Sixty";
         case "7": return "Seventy";
         case "8": return "Eighty";
         case "9": return "Ninety";
      }
   }
   else if($dig1 == "1")
   {


      switch($dig2)
      {
         case "1": return "Eleven";
         case "2": return "Twelve";
         case "3": return "Thirteen";
         case "4": return "Fourteen";
         case "5": return "Fifteen";
         case "6": return "Sixteen";
         case "7": return "Seventeen";
         case "8": return "Eighteen";
         case "9": return "Nineteen";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      $temp = $this->convertDigit($dig2);
      switch($dig1)
      {
         case "2": return "Twenty-$temp";
         case "3": return "Thirty-$temp";
         case "4": return "Forty-$temp";
         case "5": return "Fifty-$temp";
         case "6": return "Sixty-$temp";
         case "7": return "Seventy-$temp";
         case "8": return "Eighty-$temp";
         case "9": return "Ninety-$temp";
      }
   }
}

public function convertDigit($digit)
{
   switch($digit)
   {
      case "0": return "Zero";
      case "1": return "One";
      case "2": return "Two";
      case "3": return "Three";
      case "4": return "Four";
      case "5": return "Five";
      case "6": return "Six";
      case "7": return "Seven";
      case "8": return "Eight";
      case "9": return "Nine";
   }
}
```

you can call like below

```
$this->convertNumber(round($_price));
```

Comment: thanks. but i don't know where should i put this codes? which files should i create? 
im new to magento i will thankful if you explain it for me

Comment: you can put this code in any helper file and then you can call that helper anywhere you want